# Unison sync with WD NAS

Tags: sync, nas, unison

I am trying to set up a (2-way) sync with a WD mycloud mirror NAS.
The clients run Ubuntu, and I thought Unison would be a good way to do this.

I mounted the NAS share on the client, using nfs

```
sudo mount wdmycloudmirror:/nfs/Backup /mnt/wd.Backup
```

and ran Unison to sync

```
$ cat ~/.unison/wd_backup.prf
root = /home/me/sync
root = /mnt/wd.Backup
fastcheck = true
dontchmod = true
perms = 0
$ unison wd_backup
```

It takes **ages**! 9 hours to check the files, even on subsequent runs. After reading around, the solution is to install Unison on the server, which is apparently *much* faster. However I'm pretty sure WD won't allow this.

However, rsync is present:

```
$ ssh sshd@wdmycloudmirror

BusyBox v1.20.2 (2014-10-30 15:28:59 CST) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
# rsync --daemon
# ps -A | grep rsync
5468 root     2880 5     rsync --daemon
```

So, I wonder is there a way to harness this, to speed up the transfer?
Can Unison use the remote `rsync` server? SSH is set up but this doesn't work:

```
$ unison ~/sync ssh://sshd@wdmycloudmirror//nfs/Backup
Contacting server...
sh: unison: not found
Fatal error: Lost connection with the server
```

Anyone got any better ideas on how to do a fast 2-way sync in this situation?